# NodeInvocationException: The Node invocation timed out after 60000ms

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application, spa-template

I have an asp.net core web application with angular 5. In my repository layer I have a simple linq query that get data from a table. every thing works well till I change the query and join it to another entity to fetch data from two table. 
the join query get data from DB quickly and there is no delay. 
and now when I run the app I get this error:

> NodeInvocationException: The Node invocation timed out after 60000ms.
>   You can change the timeout duration by setting the
>   InvocationTimeoutMilliseconds property on NodeServicesOptions

When I run the API alone, it works well and returns Json data without any problem.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: define _the join query get data from DB quickly and there is no delay_? Do you get no delay while composing the query or when really executing (i.e. `.ToArray()`, `ToList`, `SingleOrDefault` etc. methods are called?). That's important cause the LINQ queries won't get executed until an enumeration or request method such as the above examples have been called

Comment: @Tseng: The query is really executed by ToListAsync method and gets the result from DB. As I mentioned the API works well and returns json data without any problem.

Comment: Circular references maybe?  The error comes from node, which means you have server-sided rendering enabled. Is the dataset huge? Whats the js/typescript code you run on this place?

Comment: @Tseng I Think so but even when I disable it by this code : 
 services.AddMvc() .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
it does not work